# How to verify this metric?

Tags: functional-analysis, trigonometry, metric-spaces

suppose $X$ is a measure space and $0<p<1$, the function

$$d(f,g)=||f-g||_{L^p}^p,f,g\in L^P$$

How to verify that this defines a metric?

I have thought a rather childish way: to prove $\int|a+b|^p dx \le\int|a|^p+|b|^pdx$, just to vertify
$\int|a+1|^pdx \le\int|a|^p+1dx$, so make use of $x^p$ is a upward convex function, we can get the result.

However I think this is not "functional analysis" at all, and I don't know whether it's right or wrong.

Is this right? And is there some other solution? Thank you!

Comment: @LordVader007 It's not quite the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: For $0<p<1$. Show that 
\begin{align}
|a+b|^p \leq |a|^p+|b|^p
\end{align}
for all $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$.

Additional Hint: Since $0<p<1$, then $1/p>1$ which means
\begin{align}
(|a|^p)^{1/p}+(|b|^p)^{1/p}=|a|+|b| \leq (|a|^p+|b|^p)^{1/p}.
\end{align}

Comment: yes,and this is what I mean in the question.and I wonder is there any other more "functional analysis" answer?

Comment: I hope this is ``functional analysis" enough.